# Проблема с массивом | Discord Bot | NODE.js | JavaScript | discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

такая проблема, уже неделю пытаюсь получить массив с имена участников гильдии, все мои попытки кончатся крахом, знает кто простой способ как это можно сделать?

Общая идея:
Получить массив с id пользователей => каждому id через цикл присваивать роль (т.е присвоить роль всем в гильдии), чтобы было на подобии !giverole @everyone @rolename

Comment: во что рубишься то?)

Comment: [ответ на reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/95dmqf/get_all_user_ids_on_a_server_discordjs/e3shmma)